# 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Model' - Angular2 / Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following method inside my service which returns a single record from Firebase that matches the bugId passed in:

// Note this is located within bugservice.ts

```
   getBug(bugId: string): Promise<Bug> {

    return this.bugsDbRef
        .child(bugId)
        .once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {
            const bugInfo = snapshot.val() as Bug;
            bugInfo.id = snapshot.key;
        }) as Promise<Bug>;
}
```

Inside my bugDetail component I inject the above service into my bugDetail component and then call the above method as shown here:

```
export class BugDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

private subscription: Subscription;

private bugDetail: Bug = new Bug(null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null); // Trying to populate from Service Call i.e getBug    
private bugId: string; // Come from URL

constructor(private bugService: BugService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.configureForm();

    this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
        (param: any) => {
            this.bugId = param['id'];
        });

    const t = this.bugService.getBug(this.bugId);

    console.log(t);

}
}
```

However when I console.log t the following is displayed in the console:

[image]

When I remove t and replace it with

```
this.bugDetail = this.bugService.getBug(this.bugId);
```

The error message I get is:

Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Bug'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type 'Promise'.

Can someone please explain to me how I can access the bug details retrieved from the service inside the BugDetail Component?

Comment: That's the expected behaviour; you are logging a `Promise`. To get the `Bug`, you need to call `this.bugService.getBug(this.bugId).then(bug => console.log(bug));` Also, elsewhere is your code, you call `new Bug(...)`. If `Bug` is a class, you *cannot* cast `snapshot.val()` to a `Bug`, as it's not a `Bug` instance.

Comment: Ok so now I'm confused, inside my getBug method I return a Promise<Bug> which tells me I'm passing back a bug object.  Inside my bug detail component I call this method and extend it to cater for the additional .then function you just specified. Can you help me by showing me the code for getBug function and the method to call getBug ? I'm confused by this promise stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getBug` returns a `Promise<Bug>` - which is a promise that will resolve to a `Bug` value. Promises resolve asynchronously and the resolved value is made available to the function passed to the promise's `then` method. That's the only way you can access the resolved value.

You could assign to `this.bugDetail`, like this:

```
this.bugService
    .getBug(this.bugId)
    .then(bug => { this.bugDetail = bug; });
```

You might want to read [*JavaScript Promises: an Introduction*](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises).

Comment: Thanks for the break down, and the link.  What changes do I need to make to getBug method as I'm trying to cast snapshot.val() to a Bug which is a class.  is there a way I can do this with observables?

Comment: You cannot cast it. You need to use it or its properties to create a `Bug` instance by calling `new Bug(...)` with whatever parameters the `Bug` constructor takes.

Comment: Ok makes sense, I just managed to get this working using an Observable<any> within the service, inside the bug detail component I subscribe to this event, could this be another correct way of doing it?

Comment: Whichever way you do it, you cannot cast `snapshot.val()` to a `Bug`, as the snapshot's value is not a `Bug` instance; it's an anonymous object.